# Angular's main html file can't use the styles.scss file inside the src/styles folder

Tags: html, angular, sass, directory-structure

I'm new to Angular.

In order to use the 7-1 scss pattern in my project, I created a styles folder inside the src folder "src/styles", and linked the components to the  src/styles/style.scss and it works fine.

The problem I'm having now is that the html and body elements within the main index.html file aren't affected by these styles.

Here's a look at my [directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI8xi.png)

I tried importing the styles needed inside the src/styles.scss file and it worked but I don't want to repeat my code.

1. **Wanted behavior**:

   ```
   The main index.html can use the scss styles inside the "src/styles/styles.scss" I created with no problem.
   ```
2. **Actual behavior**:

   ```
   The main index.html can only access the default style.scss folder by default
   ```

How can I fix this so that the elements inside the index.html can use the styles from within my styles folder without having to repeat my work twice?

Edit: the problem occurs despite the already made changes to the angular.json file as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p60Mc.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: please check path is proper or not ?

Comment: Are you including the entire stylesheet inside every component decorator..? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

You can add styles in the ***angular.json***. You can find styles array in the file and add the path of the style.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I had already configured my build/options/styles as well as the test/options/styles. The problem is the styles that should add certain changes  to the html and body don't since those elements are in the index.html file

Answer (score 1):

you need to add your `src/styles/styles.css` inside angular.json

there is style object

```
{ 
  "projects":{
   "yourProjectName": {
     "architect":{
       "build:{
        "options":{
          "assets":[...],
          "styles": [
           "src/styles/styles.scss",
          ]
//..rest of config
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

**Note:** After adding please restart your local development server or if in production re-deploy, to see changes

Comment: Hi Syed, thank you but I had already changed my angular.json.

Comment: Hope your problem has been solved, Insha Allah.

Answer (score 0):

npm run build after paster below command "npm start" make sure You can find screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I was able to solve the problem by importing all the sass files *from the src/styles* into the main *styles.scss* file.